# Preg_replace on html and diacritics

Tags: php, html, preg-replace, diacritics

Is there anyway to do preg_replace with that:

```
<p style="background:white">
<span style="font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;">
Coût de la prestation : 43.19 . <u></u><u></u></span></p>
```

I just want to remove or leave with spaces the price. I don't know how to define the pattern and the replacement expressions.

Hope anyone helps me!

TY.

EDIT: I just want to remove the 43.19 ., being just Coût de la prestation :

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to do ("I just want to remove or leave with spaces the price")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally what worked was:

```
preg_replace('#(Coût\s+de\s+la\s+prestation)\s*:\s*\d+(\.\d+)?#u', '$1:', $body);
```

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the [`u` modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)?

Something like:

```
preg_replace('/Coût de la prestation : (\d+\.\d{2})/u', 'whatever', $str);
```